# Can't change password

Tags: support, bug, login, password

I took the following steps to try to change my stackoverflow.com password:

- I browse to stackoverflow.com.
- Click Edit Profile & Settings.
- Click on My Logins.  There is one, Stack Exchange.
- Click "change password."
- Enter current password, new password and new password (again).
- Click Change Password.  I get "An error occurred while attempting to 
  reset password."

I know I have the correct old password because I had to use it to login here at meta.stackexchange.com.  Why can't I change my password?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did either your old or new password contain multi-byte characters? I pinged the devs since this looks suspiciously coincidental with a few other bugs that have crept up, hang tight! :)

Comment: I can confirm this bug, having followed the exact same steps myself (reported several months ago). No 'multi-byte characters' involved.

Comment: The silence from the StackExchange folks is overwhelming.  I opened a support ticket on this and I was directed to post here.  Don't think they care.

Comment: @TimPost you know, hanging tight for so long (3 weeks by now) is painful. ;)

Comment: Try tweeting .@balpha and .@Nick_Craver about the issue.

Answer (score 12):

#### Yes, it's not working..

The solution for it is **not to change your password with Stack Overflow's My Logins, instead logout your account and use the *"forget password"* option** and follow the given instruction. Here's the *"forgot your account's password"* link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

If the above link is not working, just go to the login page and find the *"forget password"* option.

Comment: Nice workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has not been fixed yet. According to the message below, "Current password" is not checked properly for some reason.

> Too many failed current password attempts; please try again later or
>   visit account recovery.

However the *"Forgot password"* option is a valid workaround, lots of users may choose not to push for it.

How did I conclude that "Change Password" was not working?

First iteration:

- Log out.
- Log in again typing the password manually. **Successful.**
- Try to change password typing Current password manually. **Fail.** *"An error occurred while attempting to reset password."*

Second iteration:

- Log out.
- Log in again using Google Chrome's password manager. **Successful.**
- Try to change password using Google Chrome's password manager. **Fail.** *"An error occurred while attempting to reset password."*

Then:

- Reset password using the "Forgot password" option.
- Repeat iterations above. Same results.

Try a different browser (Firefox):

- Log in typing the password manually. **Successful.**
- Try to change password typing Current password manually. **Fail.**

After a few months:

- Try to change the password on a different machine. **Fail.**

Comment: This is not related to the bug, and not a bug to begin with. The message is crystal clear.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou I believe I've tried enough combinations (edited the post).