# Unable to change password in Q&A software

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, password

I want to change my password. I am able to log in. After login, i tried using the **"My logins" page and change password** functionality. After I entered my current password, typed in the new one according to rules (8+ chars, 1 letter, 1 number) and submited, i got error message: **An error occurred while attempting to reset password**. I tried different new passwords, same message, no luck. (Same as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316883/287210), but the solution is not working for me, see below)

So i gave up on that method and tried to use the **"I forgot password"** functionality. The password recovery email landed in my inbox after few seconds. In next few seconds i clicked the "reset your password here" link and landed on page saying: **This link has expired...**

How can I change my password?